# Extract middle word of letter python

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I have pandas dataframe called df which look like this

```
Name
------
Mike
Noel
Kim
Anna
Luke
joseph
joe
```

How do i list only the name which has word 'n' or 'k' in the middle of the name. not the first letter nor the last letter. the result  is

```
namelist = [Mike, Anna, Luke]
```

Comment: By middle, you mean all other letters than the first or last? Because `Mike` has strictly speaking no middle letter

Comment: `df.loc[df.Name.str.contains('\w[nk]\w'), 'Name'].tolist()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can do it like this, using `str.contains` -

```
df.loc[df.Name.str.contains(r'\w[nk]\w'), 'Name'].tolist()
['Mike', 'Anna', 'Luke']
```

*Details*
First, the regex -

```
\w      # any alpha-numeric char
[nk]    # character class; letters "n" and "k"
\w      # any alpha-numeric char
```

This ensures that, if the word *begins or ends with* "n" or "k" (without containing them in the middle of the word), it is not picked up ("n" or "k" have to have something on either side).

A similar regex, to match any surrounding character (besides alphanumeric characters) would be -

```
r'.[nk].'
```

Or, if you want a regex that matches a string with "n" or "k" in the middle and anything but "n" and "k" at the ends, use -

```
r'^[^nk].*[nk].*[^nk]$'
```

Output of the `str.contains` call -

```
df.Name.str.contains(r'\w[nk]\w')

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool
```

Output of the slicing operation with `loc` -

```
df.loc[df.Name.str.contains(r'\w[nk]\w'), 'Name']

0    Mike
3    Anna
4    Luke
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Now, calling `pd.Series.tolist` gives you your list of names.

---

**Option 2**
Another option using `str.findall` -

```
df.Name.str.findall(r'^.*\w[nk]\w.*$').str[0].dropna().tolist()
['Mike', 'Anna', 'Luke']
```

Which works similar to the first, with some differences.

*Details*
First, the output of the `findall` call - a list of matches. The regex pattern is the same as above, but modified slightly to capture the entire string if the pattern in the middle is found.

```
df.Name.str.findall(r'^.*\w[nk]\w.*$')

0    [Mike]
1        []
2        []
3    [Anna]
4    [Luke]
5        []
6        []
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Get the first element from each list. Empty lists return NaNs, which are subsequently dropped -

```
df.Name.str.findall(r'.*\w[nk]\w.*').str[0].dropna()

0    Mike
3    Anna
4    Luke
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

From there, convert to list with `pd.Series.tolist`.

Comment: Your code will select "nnkk" but it should not be there as desired by OP.

Comment: @rnso Fixed that.

Comment: Can you suggest why both other answers (and even the question) got  upvotes and not my answer!

Comment: @rnso I don't usually upvote other answers (unless they're exceptionally good), and neither does the other user. Whatever the cause of the votes tally being as it is now, I was not responsible for it. Although, your method is quite inefficient, with the use of `find` and associated messiness.

Comment: For and other loops are much slower than functional methods, I believe. But for most situations I don't think that really matters. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `str[1:-1]` for remove first and last chars and then check by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
L = df.loc[df['Name'].str[1:-1].str.contains('n|k'), 'Name'].tolist()
print (L)
['Mike', 'Anna', 'Luke']
```

EDIT: If is necessary also exclude first and last `n` or `k` values:

```
m = ~df['Name'].str[0].str.lower().isin(['n','k']) &  \
    ~df['Name'].str[-1].str.lower().isin(['n','k']) & \
    df['Name'].str[1:-1].str.contains('n|k')

df = df.loc[m, 'Name'].tolist()
print (df)
['Mike', 'Anna', 'Luke']
```

Comment: Your code will select "nnkk" but it should not be there as desired by OP.

Comment: @rnso - added solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Can use list comprehension here. Following code also makes sure that names like 'nnkk' (where n and/or k are both in middle as well at one or both ends) are not selected. In addition, both lower and upper cases are managed here:

```
namelist = df.Name.tolist()              # get all names in a list
outlist = [ n
    for n in namelist
    if n[0].upper() not in ['N','K']     # conditions
       and n[-1].upper() not in ['N','K'] 
       and (n.upper().find("N") >=0 
            or n.upper().find("K") >=0) ]

print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
['Mike', 'Anna', 'Luke']
```